# Python: How to find a day week given the starting day and the amount of days to increase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have to build a time calculator as an assigment.

One of the given requeriments is to tell which day of the week will the resulting time be.

For example: `12:00 AM Monday + 24:00` should return `12:00 AM Tuesday`

And the code I currently use does that, but I found a bug that suggest I'm approaching this wrong, so I would like to get your help to notice what can I do about this.

When I get the same day I started, instead of the index being 0 it is 7, and I get the `list index out of range` error.

This is my function

```
def dayFind(startDay, increment):

    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    week = len(days)
    index = days.index(startDay)

    day = days[index + increment % 7]
       
    return day

    print(dayFind("Tuesday", 20)) # Returns IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: You are close, but have a simple logic error in your equation. Ask yourself how your equation works if your start day is Sunday (hint - you get lots of index out of range errors).

Comment: @scott, you made me think, but I still can't find what you mean. Can you provide me with more information?

Comment: To solve your way, you need to use modulo twice - first to remove even weeks and then again after you add the residual to your start: day = days[(index + (increment % 7))%7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod (%) operator has the same precedence as multiplication, so it gets evaluated before your addition. You should write `days[(index + increment) % 7]`.

Comment: This definitely solved the issue of out of range, but somehow, ends up adding a day to the actual result, and also the hour sum ends up being different, which makes me more confused because it works for the rest of the tests. This is the only test I havent been able to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
day = days[index + increment % 7]
```

with :

```
index = index + increment//24
if index//7 >=1:
    index = index %7
day = days[index]
```

`increment//24` return an int rounded to greatest integer less than the quotient.

For example
when input is 20 the floor division gives 0 which means the day should not change

when input is 40 the floor division gives 1 so only 1 day is incemented.